# @flask_login.login_required not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, flask, firebase-realtime-database, flask-login

I am using flask_login for implementing auth in my flask application

Here are the ***unauthorized_handler*** and ***login_required*** enabled method

```
@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized_handler():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
# use decorators to link the function to a url

@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
@flask_login.login_required
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html')
```

I am using firebase as my backend service

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    auth = firebase.auth()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(request.form['email'], request.form['password'])
            if user != None:
                return redirect(url_for('profile'))
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            response = e.args[0].response
            error = response.json()['error']['code']
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login.html')
```

The problem is that after I login(which is successfull) the app is automatically redirected to the `/login` url instead of `/profle`.

I tried turning my debug mode off and on still not working.

Comment: I think  user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(request.form['email'], request.form['password']) returns None (some case maybe). Your code looks okay though.

Answer (score 3):

It can be a case of a double redirect happening, where you first get redirected to profile, and then the `login_required` decorator kicks in redirecting you back to login, because from the point of view of `flask_login` you are not logged in yet.

You might have retrieved user credentials from firebse, but with `flask_login` you have to also call [`login_user`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.login_user) function. (Also see [Login Example](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example) of flask login's page)